# How can I get shockwave flash to work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: flash

I've tried most of the things suggested on this site and others so far. It's kind of frustrating because this is a home computer and I mainly use it for browsing the internet and watching YouTube videos. When I try to install something that might fix it, it just downloads a bunch of files and says to extract them or whatever. I'm not sure what to do with the files after I extract them. That's probably the main issue: I don't have a lot of experience working with computers at this level. I'm used to Windows, which seems to make most software installs idiot-proof. Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 7):

The Flash Player can be installed from the **Multiverse** repository:  `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`. You need to make sure that you have the Multiverse repo enabled: **System Settings** > **Software & Updates**.

An easy and quick way to get it working though is to just install Google Chrome by going to this link and following the directions: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Chrome builds Flash into the browser itself so it means if you have the browser, you have Flash.

Comment: "You need to make sure that you have the Multiverse repo enabled: [Synaptic: Settings > Repositories > Ubuntu Software]." Sorry to be ignorant, but where do I put that in? I've already installed Chrome, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I found the fix! I uninstalled the Adobe flash player, and now it works. Not sure why, but now I can watch YouTube videos in either Firefox or Chrome, and websites that require flash work now as well. On YouTube, it still asks you to install a plugin, but then it plays it anyway. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: the question is about shockwave, not adobe flash player.

Answer (score 3):

You could install Adobe Flash Player for flash support: `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Tried that too. Still nothing. I've also tried the ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Answer (score 1):

The Shockwave player is only available for Windows. You can use mozplugger(a program that lets you "embed" other programs in your web browser.) along with wine and windows version of firefox

- First, install the wine and mozplugger packages (from the software center).
- Now download and install the Windows version of Firefox . Download it from [Mozilla's web site](http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-4.0.1&os=win&lang=en-US). Now double click it and install it .
- Run the windows version of firefox .
- Now go to a web site [that requires Shockwave](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/), and choose to get the missing plugin. Again, follow the on-screen instructions, and when the plugin has installed and is working, you may close Firefox.
- Now you need to configure mozplugger to use the Windows version of Firefox for Shockwave files. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

  `gksudo gedit`

then open the /etc/mozpluggerrc file

Add the following two lines to the end of the file:

```
application/x-director: dir,dcr,dxr,cst,cct,cxt,w3d,fgd,swa: Macromedia Director file
        swallow(firefox.exe) fill stream: wine "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" -chrome "$file"
```

Now open a Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and paste

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/pluginreg.dat
```

Now run the native version of firefox and test the shockwave player by visting [this site](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/) .

[Modified From Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Shockwave)